# Programming for Android 5 without AppCompat

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-appcompat

I understand that it is considered good practice to program for Android using the *AppCompat* support libraries for backwards compatibility. However, for this specific project, the minimum API level I am to support is Android 5.0 (level 22).

However all information I can find for new Lollipop features always points towards the *AppCompat* support libraries. Must I do this, or are there vanilla equivalents that **do not require *AppCompat*** themes, classes or attention to backwards compatibility (ie. a plain *CoordinatorLayout* in layout XML instead of *android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout*)?

Comment: Sooner or later the support libraries will be backporting API 30 stuff into lollipop :-)

Comment: "However all information I can find for new Lollipop features always points towards the AppCompat support libraries" -- [vast quantities of what came in Android 5.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html) have nothing to do with AppCompat. For example, `CoordinatorLayout` has nothing to do with Android 5.0. It tangentially has to do with Material Design. Also note that API Level 22 is Android 5.1, not 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

First, Andorid 5.0 is API 21. If you set the min SDK to 21, most features like material design theme comes by default, you don't need any libraries. But I think the CoordinatorLayout is only in the com.android.support:design library, you have to include the library to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use various support libs for certain functionality.

The CoordinatorLayout exists in the design library, and not in the OS framework.

This can actually be quite useful. Use of the design library means you can use these components independently from the OS version of the user's device. Meaning you can get updated functionality without the user updating their OS.

And won't experience breaking API differences depending on what OS the user runs.